# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\User' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to implement Socialiate for Laravel 5.5 using this guide https://scotch.io/tutorials/laravel-social-authentication-with-socialite. Data is returned properly from the provider, but I am having trouble defining Use and Namespaces.

With this configuration:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Socialite;
```

The result is:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\User' not found

Triggered by:

```
$authUser = User::where('providerId', $user->id)->first();
```

But, if I add App\User:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Socialite;
```

The result is:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found

Triggered by:

```
Auth::login($authUser, true);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you do $authUser = \User::where('providerId', $user->id)->first();

Comment: read this https://github.com/laravel/socialite it's will help you

Comment: Then I get "Class 'User' not found"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didnt import `Auth` namespace the right way.

The proper namespace is `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` at the top of your class.

Comment: I ended up just adding **use Auth;** because the path was in my app.php aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Try Also, adding **use App\User;**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Socialite;
use App\User;
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case help came when i see that included files were only user and not the socialproviders table in the name space i use two tables Users and Social_providers .. it took 2 days to resolve eaten 4 gb data.

```
enter code here

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Socialite;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\socialProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
//use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class RegisterController extends Controller
```